# shell script to walk folders and sub-folders, convert time stamp to UTC format, and export .csv file

Tags: shell, csv, filenames

**Hello everyone** !

I have some huge amount of image files (around 100 000) spared into 50 folders and sub-folders and i need to write a script in order to treat this data automatically

I am trying to write a **Shell script** for a bit complicated task, and i am now struggling to make it run the correct way. So, in order to give you the best description possible, i am going to write down the main things that i want to get done with this script as follows:

first: The script must go over Folders and sub-folders and extract filenames and full Path

Second: The filenames contain time and date informations .ie: 
20180612074405680. I need the script to convert this to the **UTC format** .ie: 2018 - 06 - 12 T 07:44:05 TZ +01:00

Finally: I need all this to be exported to a .csv file,

I have been trying to use the `find` command in order to walk folders and sub-folders and get filenames but i still couldn't get the full path of the files

Can anyone please help or give some hints !

Answer (score 1):

Well,

- To get absolute paths with `find`, you can either prepend the base path to `find`, or if you're already on that path, use `$(pwd)`, so either:

`find /path/to/my/files`

`find $(pwd)`

- To convert this format to UTC, I don't see a point to look for some date conversion tool, it would be easier to simply alter the string, E.G:

`echo "${filename:0:4} - ${filename:4:2} - ${filename:6:2} T ${filename:8:2}:${filename:10:2}:${filename:12:2} TZ +01:00"`

Since you're converting all those files from the same timezone and probably on the same day, it would always be the same timezone, so you can simply find out what it is and append it literally.

Comment: Hello @giladmayani, thank you for the quick answer, but how i think this solution is not for going through all the 50 folders and get the filenames in the same time,
Also, how i can export this to a single .csv file ?

Comment: Hi @YacineWalid, If you run `find $(pwd) -type f` on the base folder it will output the names of all files in all folders and subfolders. You can then iterate over the output of `find` with the `for` loop, do whatever processing you want with each filename and write it to a .csv file you create. Read more about shell `for` loops and writing to files (with `echo` and `>`).

Comment: your answer is really helpful, i will follow your advices but i'm still struggling to get exactly what i want as i am a real noob at shell scripting, anyway, if it is possible for you to bring me more details so that i can get closer to my end goal, it would be amazing